# Are there any region specific advertising platforms, alternative to AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I'm wondering if AdSense is the best advertising platform to use for international/multi-lingual websites. When trying an [AdSense sandbox preview tool](http://www.labnol.org/google-adsense-sandbox/), I have noticed that for example the Chinese version of the site shows *some* Chinese adverts, but mostly they are English. I have tried searching for "Chinese alternative to AdSense" but can't find anything specific to a region. I suppose I could just try [this top 10 list](http://www.rosswalker.co.uk/adsense_top10/), and see which performs the best?